# HTTPD benchmarking tool that parses output

Tags: apache-http-server, webserver, javascript, benchmarking, httpd

I'm trying to benchmark a HTTP server.

It's becoming quite obvious that I won't get accurate numbers if the tool being used doesn't parse any output (the JavaScript and HTML). Does anyone know of a tool that does this?

Comment: Are you saying the tool has to execute the JavaScript to find other resources to load? It might end up being a benchmark of the tool's parser and JS engine and your content more than a benchmark of your httpd.

Comment: Do to the inherent nature of ajax I find that there will not be a tool to do such a thing. ajax would be yet another http request executing asynchronously after the first data set is transmitted. I was chasing a ghost.

Comment: You might want to ask on ServerFault, and ask for a website or web application performance test tool, not an "httpd" test tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently im chasing a ghost. ajax requests would inherently be another http request delivered asynchronously after a result is recieved